# bitmap.Save with a network location

Tags: bitmap

I am trying to use `bitmap.Save` to store images in a network location (not my local drive). But, when I use below code I see the error "A generic error occurred in GDI+". Am I approaching this in the wrong way?

```
try{
    Rectangle bounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);
    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
        }
        bitmap.Save(@"\\machineName\temp", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to give the proper path of the other machine. Generally, machineName will mean that you are trying to save the image in the C drive itself of the machine. It is not possible due to some security reasons. Create a new folder in the C drive of the other machine and inside that folder, try to save the image. That might help.